# Help to identify physics behind Valve patent on "variable optical correction using spatially varying polarizers"

Tags: optics, liquid-crystal

Apparently, there is a way to vary optical power by employing spatially varying polarizers. [The patent](https://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2021/0247631.html) is almost unreadable. My understanding is that they propose to stack spatially varying polarizers into a single optical unit and by enabling/disabling individual layers, achieve desired optical correction:

> When inactive,... the spatially varying polarizer may be optically clear or may only perform inherent optical correction associated with the material composition of the spatially varying polarizer. Materials of various types have optical properties and are operative to change light. ... The spatially varying polarizer may be formed of **two or more twisted liquid crystal layers**. The liquid crystal layers of the spatially varying polarizer when turned off may still perform inherent optical correct. When turned on, the spatially varying polarizer performs the optical correction it has been designed to perform.

The paper however says absolutely noting about how spatially varying polarizers actually work. They are formed out of two+ layers of liquid crystals and can be optically neutral when turned off but behave as a refractive component when turned on.

Is there any prior work on using polarizers to focus light? What could plausibly be used to achieve lens-like behavior from 2 layers of liquid crystals? Their polarizers are spatially non-uniform so I suspect the mechanism is diffractive in nature.

Answer (score 0):

The better googleable name is **Geometric Phase Lens**. It relies on manipulation of Pancharatnam-Berry phase via spatially varying polarizers, often MTR (Multi Twist Retarders). Another name is chiral meta-lens.
https://www.osa-opn.org/home/articles/volume_27/february_2016/features/controlling_light_with_geometric-phase_holograms/